# Wrap H1-H6 Tags with Typo3 ParseFunc depending on the class set in RTE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want to add inline-svgs to my h1 to h6 Tags depending on the class set in the RTE.

Example:
RTE:

```
<h1 class="icon--clock">Header</h1>
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="icon--clock"><svg>...</svg>Header</h1>
```

I've done something similar with links before, using the parseFunc Config. A method like this: https://wiki.typo3.org/External_links

Is there any way to access and split the tag and class like the link parameters through TypoScript?

I also tried using a userFunc

```
lib.parseFunc.userFunc = ...\MyClass->MyUserFunc
```

but in Params I only get the tag content, not the tag or the classes that have been set themselves.

I'm using Typo8 with the ckeditor, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Can I even do this?
How do I do this?

I know that I can alternatively add different header layouts and use the tt_content header field, because it's easier to manipulate the template there. But I'd love to know if there is a way to this in the RTE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do it in typoscript, but that would be very complicated as you need to analyze the attributes of the Hn-tags.

A simpler method which came to mind would be: use CSS and `::before`. So you can use a selector to the class to insert the matching SVG.
This also can be done with javascript but as CSS can do it it would be more efficient to use CSS.

Comment: You're right, CSS is another alternative. And probably the fastest, too. I'd still prefer the actual svg-code to be added to my html though, because I want to manipulation the svg code later on.

Comment: maybe you can insert the CSS (with the inline-SVG?) dynamically in the content? then there is the javascript-variant. Otherwise I would go for a PHP variant as the only typoscript solutions I can imagine are either very complex (split, compare, join, ...) or bad style (adding an 'attribute' which closes the tag and opens others: `x-data="dummy"><svg>...</svg`)